# instagram api jquery not displaying pictures correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, instagram-api

I'm still quite new to Jquery and Javascript and I'm having some problems using the API provided here

https://github.com/potomak/jquery-instagram

I'm trying to loop and grab multiple batches of pictures and display all of them into a div.  This is a part of my current code:

```
$('#morebutton').click(function(){
var numtimes = 3;
console.log("main fun  " + numtimes)
GetMorePictures(numtimes);
});

function GetMorePictures(numtimes) {
    //$("#pictures").html($("#pictures").html() + "<h1>Page " + pagenum++ + "</h1>")
    if (numtimes == 0) {
        return
    }
    console.log("inside fun  " + numtimes)
  $('.instagram2').instagram({
    search: {
    lat: lat,
    lng: lng,
    distance: document.getElementById('Distance').value,
    max_timestamp: ( (document.getElementById("Timing").selectedIndex == 1)? null:nexttime),
    min_timestamp: ( (document.getElementById("Timing").selectedIndex == 1)? prevtime:null)
  },
    count : 100,
    clientId: '7d428aff533f40e1b3d5f919882576d2'
  });

}

$('.instagram2').on('willLoadInstagram', function(event, options) {
    console.log(options);
});

$('.instagram2').on('didLoadInstagram', function(event, response) {
    console.log("just loaded")
    console.log(response)
    //console.log("1")
    prevtime = response.data[0].created_time
    nexttime = response.data[response.data.length - 1].created_time
    var inputTag = document.getElementById("Tag");
    if (inputTag && inputTag.value) {
        for (i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
            if ( $.inArray(inputTag.value, response.data[i].tags) > -1 ) {
                if(i != 0){
                    $("#pictures").html($("#pictures").html() + "<a href='"+response.data[i].link+"' target='_blank'> <img src='"+response.data[i].images.thumbnail.url+"' height=150 width=150 /> </a>")
                }
            }   
        }
    }else {
        for (i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
            if(i != 0){
                $("#pictures").html($("#pictures").html() + "<a href='"+response.data[i].link+"' target='_blank'> <img src='"+response.data[i].images.thumbnail.url+"' height=150 width=150 /> </a>")
            }
        }
    }
    //console.log("2")
    if( $('#pictures').is(':empty') ) {$("#pictures").html($("#pictures").html() + "No Result, Try another search or load more results")}
    searched = true;
    console.log("about to recur");
    GetMorePictures(numtimes - 1);
});
```

I've tried moving things around both inside and outside the GetMorePictures function but It's not working correctly.  If they're in the function then they display multiple times and if they're outside the function then they dont display at all.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The call to `GetMorePictures(numtimes - 1)` can't work properly because you're referencing `numtimes` that is undefined in the context of the `didLoadInstagram` event callback. For a quick and dirty fix try to move the definition of that variable outside the `onclick` callback.